# How to display image when converting HTML to image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I had successfully converted html to image using the below code but however font was changing and image is not displaying on image.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://files.codepedia.info/files/uploads/iScripts/html2canvas.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div_card"  style="border-color:grey;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;width:600px; height:450px; padding:15px;margin-left:40px">
       <div style="display:inline-block;height:20px;"> <div id="sp_name"> Author:John Michael Smith Junior</div></div><br>
       <div style="display:inline-block;height:120px; width: 120px; float:right"> 
          <img src="htmlimage.jpg" style="height:120px; width: 120px"> </div>
       <div style="display:inline-block;height:20px;"><div> Published on March 1982 </div></div><br>
       <div style="display:inline-block;height:20px;"> <div> Published by: Mark Vin book house</div></div><br>
       <div style="display:inline-block;height:20px;"> <div>Last Edition Dec 1999</div></div><br>
       <div style="display:inline-block;height:20px;"> <div>Sold Copies: 150000</div></div><br>      
    </div>
    <a id="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
    <br />
    <div id="previewImage" style="display: none;">
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var element = $("#div_card"); // global variable
            var getCanvas; // global variable

            html2canvas(element, {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
                    getCanvas = canvas;
                }
            });

            $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {
                var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
                var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
                $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "your_pic_name.png").attr("href", newData);
            });
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to get image without change in font.How can I do that??????

Comment: No reply from anyone in this world

Answer (score 1):

### No need canvas is image like

There are many ways to convert a canvas to an image. However why bother as the canvas is image like in its behavior. Just display the canvas as if it were an image.

Contemporary [`html2canvas`](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/getting-started) usage example, adding captured canvas to page

```
html2canvas(document.body).then(canvas => document.body.appendChild(canvas));
```

### Using your example

Note security prevents it from working in the SO snippet.

```js
addEventListener("load",() => {
    html2canvas(divCard)
      .then(can => {
          // show result of html2canvas
          previewImage.classList.remove("hide");
          previewImage.appendChild(can);

          // show download link and add data url for download.
          downloadLink.classList.remove("hide");
          downloadLink.download = "canvasCap.png";  // name the download file
          downloadLink.href = can.toDataURL("image/png").replace("data:image/png", "data:application/octet-stream");
      })
      .catch(error => {
          previewImage.textContent = "html2canvas error: " + error.message;
          previewImage.classList.remove("hide");
          previewImage.classList.add("error");
      });
});
```

```css
* { font-family: arial }
.hide { display: none }
.error {color: red }
.titile {font-size: x-large}
#divCard {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://files.codepedia.info/files/uploads/iScripts/html2canvas.js"></script>

<div id="divCard">
  <div class="titile">Author:John Michael Smith Junior</div>
  <div>Published on March 1982 </div>
  <div>Published by: Mark Vin book house</div>
  <div>Last Edition Dec 1999</div>
  <div>Sold Copies: 150000</div>
</div>
<h4>HTML2CANVAS result...</h4>
<a id="downloadLink" class="hide">download</a>
<div class="hide" id="previewImage"></div>
```

<sub><sup>BTW Its 2020.. jQuery is slow bloated baggage.  Windows ended support for IE <11 on Jan31 this year removing the last argument for jQuery relevance.</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with. It allows remote and custom fonts to be included properly in the output image. It requires the latest version of Chrome:

1. Open the HTML page (that you wish to convert to an image) in Chrome.
2. Right click anywhere in the background of the displayed page, and select "Save As".
3. In the Save As dialog, select the "Save as type" option for "Webpage, Single file (*.mhtml)", then select the folder and file name you want to save as. This will convert the HTML into MHTML and save it locally. The file size will be *huge* because it includes all the custom fonts, and potentially static images, in the file.
4. Go to the command line shell of your local machine and use headless Chrome to take a screenshot of the locally saved .mhtml file as a PNG file.

   E.g, if your machine is Windows 10, the locally saved file is "C:\tmp\page.mhtml", and it is a 16x16 image, use:

   > "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --headless --disable-gpu --screenshot=C:\tmp\page.png --window-size="16,16" --default-background-color=0 file:///C/tmp/page.mhtml

This will save the top left 16x16 window of your rendered HTML page as a PNG file at: C:\tmp\image.png.